# How to remove all elements that satisfy a condition in array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I implement this in Ruby? Is there any one line of code technique?
Let's say I want to get rid of all the elements which are less than 3 of an integer array.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use either `new_array = array.reject {|x| x < 3}` (`reject` returns a new array) or `array.reject! {|x| x < 3}` (`reject!` aka `delete_if` modifies the array in place).

There's also the (somewhat more common) `select` method, which acts like `reject` except that you specify the condition to keep elements, not to reject them (i.e. to get rid of the elements less than 3, you'd use `new_array = array.select {|x| x >= 3}`).

Comment: Ruby's [`#delete_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) and [`#reject!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) are slightly different. `reject!` returns `nil` if no items were changed and changes the array at each time the block is called.

Answer (score 28):

Probably worth pointing out that

```
array.reject! {|x| x < 3}
```

and

```
array.delete_if {|x| x < 3}
```

Are the same, but

```
array.reject {|x| x < 3}
```

Will still return the same result, but not change the "array".

Answer (score 12):

```
  a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
  a.delete_if {|x| x >= "b" }   #=> ["a"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for numbers and letters in alphabetical order. their values are compared, what if the conditions change?

```
array = ["Type", ": Jointed", "Axes", ": 6", "Reach", ": 951 mm", "Capacity", ": 6 Kg", "Uses", ": ", "Arc welding, material handling, machine loading, application", "This particular unit is in excellent condition with under 700 hours."]
```

We need to delete all elemetns after the "Uses" value
example:

```
array = ["Type", ": Jointed", "Axes", ": 6", "Reach", ": 951 mm", "Capacity", ": 6 Kg"]
```

So, that desition is not working (it just remove one element):

```
array.delete_if {|x| x >= "Uses" }
["Type", ": Jointed", "Axes", ": 6", "Reach", ": 951 mm", "Capacity", ": 6 Kg", ": ", "Arc welding, material handling, machine loading, application", "This particular unit is in excellent condition with under 700 hours."]
```