# Removing elements of an array that are evenly divisible by 3

Tags: ruby

How can I remove elements from a given array of integers that are evenly divisible by 3? A new array should be returned and the original array should not be altered.

For example, if

```
array = [1,2,3,4,1,5,2,6,7,8,9,10,7,11,12,13,14,15]
```

the array

```
[1, 2, 4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 8, 10, 7, 11, 13, 14]
```

should be returned.

Comment: Please, show us what you tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all elements that satisfy a condition in array in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006198/how-to-remove-all-elements-that-satisfy-a-condition-in-array-in-ruby)

Comment: Sharp, one problem with your statement of the question was your choice of example. By making the array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]` readers might conclude you wanted to remove every third element rather than every element that equals a multiple of `3`. Also, always make it clear whether you want to return a new object and leave the original object unchanged, or modify (*mutate*) the original object.

Comment: Readers: if you believe the edited question is now clear, please consider voting to reopen. Note that the answer given by the OP is consistent with the current statement of the question.

Answer (score 7):

Just found it:

```
array.reject{|a| a % 3 == 0}
```

Comment: This works. You might also want to look into the `reject!` method, which modifies the array variable.

Comment: It does not modify the array variable. It modifies the array. That is completely different. A thing and a name of a thing are two different things.